How to automaticly expand tabulator subtable when a row contains a multi-line cell?
I have a Tabulator table with a subtable. After loading data in the main table, data is loaded to the subtable. Each row in the subtable has some columns which contain data which is loaded asynchronously from the server. After fetching the data, the row.update({...}) function is called which then triggers the cell formatter for that cell. The cell formatter formats the data in 2 rows (inside the cell).
The row height is expanded to fit the contents of the cell, but the table and subtable remain the same height which causes a scrollbar to appear for the subtable.
I tried calling cell.checkHeight() and cell.getRow().normalizeHeight() using the onRendered parameter of cellFormatter , setting the variableHeight: true option in the columns definition and various css hacks, but none of that worked. When calling cell.getTable().redraw() or cell.getRow().reformat() using the onRendered parameter of cellFormatter it ends up causing an infinite loop.
What I would want is for the subtable to automatically expand itself causing the main table to expand itself. Any help is appreciated


var tableData = [{
  name: "qwerty",
  subtable: [{
    name: "single line value"
  }]
}];


function childTableCellFormatter(cell) {
  if (cell.getData().loaded) {
    return cell.getValue();
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    cell.getRow().update({
      name: "multi line <br> value",
      loaded: true
    })
  }, 1000);

  return cell.getValue();
}

function rowFormatter(row) {
  var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
  holderEl.style.paddingLeft = "20px";
  row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

  var subtable = new Tabulator(holderEl, {
    layout: 'fitDataFill',
    data: row.getData().subtable,
    columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      formatter: childTableCellFormatter
    }]
  });
  subtable.on("tableBuilt", () => table.redraw());
}

var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  layout: 'fitDataFill',
  data: tableData,
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name"
  }],
  rowFormatter: rowFormatter
});
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="table"></div>



JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wk5zcvr4/

Please look at [ask]. We want to see the code here. Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] to provide a [mcve]

Thanks for the explanation. I have posted a snipped of the code here. I don't know why the "Run snippet" button isn't showing, because it's showing when I'm editing the post.

I fixed that for you

One approach could be to use rowUpdated event instead of tableBuilt and adding another redraw to the subtable formatter. This requires couple redraws and may have some side effects but seems to work for the example you provided.
Also see the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py78ownq/


var tableData = [
    {name:"qwerty", subtable: [{name: "single line value"}]}
];


function childTableCellFormatter(cell) {
    if(cell.getData().loaded) {
    return cell.getValue();
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    cell.getRow().update({name: "multi line <br> value", loaded:  true})
    
    cell.getTable().redraw();
  }, 1000);
  
  return cell.getValue();
}

function rowFormatter(row) {
    var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
  holderEl.style.paddingLeft = "20px";
  row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);
  
  var subtable = new Tabulator(holderEl, {
    layout: 'fitDataFill',
    data: row.getData().subtable,
    columns: [ {title:"Name", field:"name", formatter: childTableCellFormatter }]
  });
  
  subtable.on("rowUpdated", () => table.redraw());
}

var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    layout: 'fitDataFill',
  data: tableData,
  columns: [ {title:"Name", field:"name"}],
  rowFormatter: rowFormatter
});
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="table"></div>



